# Rails 3: How to seed an array to a seed.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an `interests` table that only has a `:name` attribute.

I'm trying to seed (via `seed.rb`) the following array so that they all display in my form (checkbox)... How would I do that?

Is there a better way than storing this in `seed.rb`?

```
[ "Adventure Sports", "Arts and Crafts", "Beauty/Hair", 
  "Books", "Dining Out", "Fine Art", "Fine Jewelry", 
  "Gardening", "Golf" ]
```

Comment: Please format code using a four-space indentation before it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to put it into your seed.rb, you create them like you would elsewhere, e.g.

```
[ "Adventure Sports", "Arts and Crafts"].each do |interest|
  Interest.create!({:name => interest})
end
```

Alternatively, you could store them in your Model as a constant and use that in your form.

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  INTERESTS = [ "Adventure Sports", "Arts and Crafts" ]
end
```

And then in your form e.g.:

```
f.select Interest::INTERESTS
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `find_or_create_by_...` to ensure that records are only created once even if the `seeds.rb` is run again:

```
[ "Adventure Sports", "Arts and Crafts"].each do |interest|
  Interest.find_or_create_by_name(interest)
end
```

With `name` being the column name. If column name is e.g. `title` use `find_or_create_by_title`.

It can also be used to set more than one column e.g.:

```
[["Adam", 10], ["Allan", 20], ["Andy", 30]].each do |data|
  role = Role.find_by_name("editor").id
  User.find_or_create_by_name_and_credits_and_role_id(data[0], data[1], role)
end
```